# ¿Qué significa una virgulilla [~] dentro de una gramática [Grammar] de Raku (Perl 6)?

Tags: raku

Encontré una virgulilla en esta [gramática (Grammar) del módulo Config::INI de Raku](https://github.com/tadzik/perl6-Config-INI/blob/master/lib/Config/INI.pm#L16):

```
token header { ^^ \h* '[' ~ ']' $<text>=<-[ \] \n ]>+ \h* <.eol>+ }
```

No tengo ninguna virgulilla en el texto con que este patrón coincide. Sé que `'[' ~ ']'` es importante porque si quito cualquier (o dos o todos) de estos tres símbolos, el patrón deja de coincidir con el texto.

Cambié la expresión así y funciona:

```
token header   { ^^ \h* '[' $<text>=<-[ \] \n ]>+ ']' \h* <.eol>+ }
```

Me parece que `'[' ~ ']'` significa que lo que sigue estará dentro de un pareja de `[` y `]`.

Sé que en la sintaxis normal de Raku, se usa la virgulilla `~` para la concatenación, pero este ejemplo está dentro de [una gramática](http://doc.perl6.org/language/grammars) ('Grammar'). (En Raku, se puede usar la gramática para sacar datos estructurados de texto). Busqué la [documentación](https://doc.perl6.org/) de [las gramáticas](http://doc.perl6.org/language/grammars) y de [las expresiones regulares](http://doc.perl6.org/language/regexes) para una sola `~`, pero no encontré ninguna dentro de una gramática ni dentro de una expresión regular tampoco.

---

["cross-posted" en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247264)

Comment: eso se llama técnicamente __"rabo'e cochino"__, aquí y en pekín.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomado (y traducido) de la [documentación](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#New_metacharacters) de Apocalypse 5 (sintaxis para regexes) en la sección "New Metacharacters":

> El operador ~ es una ayuda para hacer coincidir sub-reglas anidadas
>   con un terminador específico. Está diseñado para ser colocado entre
>   paréntesis de abertura y cierre, así:
>
> ```
>  '(' ~ ')' <expression>
> ```

En esa explicación también esta el [link](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/S05-metachars/tilde.t#L6-L81) a las pruebas correspondientes en el repositorio del test suite (roast) de Perl6.